# Installing windows xp keeps repeating setup from USB

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation

I'm trying to install windows XP from USB but after setup copies the files. It says it has to restart. And when it restarts, it comes back again  on the setup. It is repeating the same process again and again. I need to control the loop and go into installation after the copy of the xp installation files.

After unplugging the USB I'm getting this error `"Windows could not start because of a computer disk hardware configuration problem. Couldn't read from the selected boot device.Check boot path and disk hardware"`

Comment: Well, I'm sure I misunderstood, but after it's installed, what happens when you unplug the USB before it boots up?

Comment: Its not installed yet .. it says its copying windows file to my c drive after that it says it need to restart to install windows xP

Comment: How are you installing it - I assume you've set the USB as a boot drive?

Comment: Yeah  ....I will try to unplug and see what will happen.

Comment: After unplugging I'm getting this error "Windows could not start because of a computer disk hardware configuration problem. Couldn't read from the selected boot device.Check boot path and disk hardware"

Comment: It's not trying to actually install onto itself is it? Other than that situation, maybe a file (or several) are missing/corrupt on the installation media?

Comment: No i'm trying to install on my HD

Comment: After the files are copied, make sure you boot from the **hard-disk** and not the USB stick. Booting from the installation media will just restart the setup process. However, unplugging the stick will not help as it needs to get some files off the installation media.

Comment: OK - it sounds like the image/files you have are not the correct ones. Where did you get them from?

Comment: I'm downloading a new copy of the windows xP and I will try to install it through USB and check if the issue remains the same.